# C# weka.dll is missing DenseInstance-class

Tags: c#, dll, weka

I converted the WEKA.jar from my Weka-installation (3.6) via ikvmc to a library (dll) to use it in C#.
I added the library as a reference in my C#-Project in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. After that, i used many classes of the weka library and everything works fine. But now, I want to create an object of the class **DenseInstance** but VS2013 cannot find this class in **weka.core.***.

```
 using weka.classifiers.meta;
 using weka.classifiers;
 using weka.core;
 using weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute;

 ...
 DenseInstance instance = new DenseInstance(2); 
 ...
```

I had no errors during the conversion of the .jar to the library file. 
Can somebody help me?

DJTrust

Comment: check if your DenseInstance - is not private/internal in your weka.core class

Comment: I didn't create the class **DenseInstance**. It is a class from the WEKA-library and allowed to use it to create objects from it.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. In Weka 3.6, the functionality of **DenseInstance** is integrated in the class **Instance**. So, instead of **DenseInstance** you have to chosse **Instance** in this case. Now it works.